# c++ polymorphism/pure virtual function

Tags: c++, polymorphism, pure-virtual

I have a class called course. Course has a pointer to a base class called Assessment.

```
class Course{
    char* courseName;
    float fee;

public:
    Assessment* assessment;
    Course();
    Course(Course&);
    Course(char*, float, Assessment *);
    ~Course();
    friend ostream& operator <<(ostream& os, Course&);
};
```

Strickly for testing purposes, in the constructor i'm assigning the Assessment pointer to an ExamAssessment(a sub-class)

```
Course::Course(){
    courseName = "something";
    fee = 0;
    assessment = &ExamAssessment(45);
}
```

My driver code looks like this

```
Course t = Course();
cout << *(t.assessment);
```

In assessment, Report is a pure virtual

```
virtual void Report() = 0;
```

The problem is when I cout the assessment, in the assessment overloaded operator '<<', I'm calling Report()

```
ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, Assessment& assessment){
    assessment.Report();
    os << "Course Grade: "<< assessment.grade << endl;
    return os;
}
```

But the Report is calling 'Assessments' Report instead of ExamAssessments Report. Not sure where I'm going wrong with this(I'm fairly new to C++ inheritance)

Comment: How do you know it is calling 'Assessments' Report?

Comment: Compiler is telling me 'A pure virtual function was called'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `Course::Course()` you should never do that

```
 assessment = &ExamAssessment(45);
```

You're taking the address of a temporary. That will be invalid as soon as you're out of the constructor scope. And I think the compiler warned you !
That explain your crash unexpected behaviour when you're accessing assessment.

Do:

```
 assessment = new ExamAssessment(45);
```

And as @Michael K. Sondej said  delete it in the destructor. Or use [`std::unique_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr).

Comment: Yea it works :). Still crashing somewhere but it's printing right lol